# Finding the Dimension of OBJ objects

Tags: graphics, 3d, collision-detection

I am having a Three `OBJ` file, `Cone, Sphere and Cube`. How can I find the dimension of these objects, so that I can use it in my collision detection class?

i.e How can I find `Radius, Length of Cube and Radius and Height of cone`? Or is there any better way for collision detection, I have hundreds of random particle in my game which may or may not collide with these objects.

Comment: For the sphere and cube you can find the minimum and maximum x,y and z coords from obj and calculate center and raduis or length. For the cone it may work too but you need to know how exactly it is oriented in order to know which min max values to use for the height and radius.

Comment: What's a radius of a Cube?

Comment: @ybungalobill That's i don't know  i having a OBJ file for Cube

Comment: @user6250837: The question about the radius was a hint toward you. Here's the second hint, from me: Cubes don't have a radius (sphere's do).

Comment: @datenwolf Here i called Sherlock to solve the above hint he said that find the distance between every 2 vertex , the maximum will be radius of sphere...  is he right ?

Comment: woo sorry he forget to add 2*radius....

Answer (score 0):

Length of the cube would be the distance of two consecutive points in one face.
If by radius of a cube you mean its diagonal it would be sqrt{3} of its length.

For a sphere, you can find its center by averaging all the vertices.
Its radius would be the distance between any vertex and the center. 
It works fine if the sphere is not high resolution.
Otherwise, you have to solve a system of equations to find the sphere that passes through four points. You can take a look at this:
https://www.quora.com/How-do-you-find-the-center-and-radius-of-a-sphere-given-any-four-arbitrary-points-x_1-y_1-z_1-x_2-y_2-z_2-x_3-y_3-z_3-x_4-y_4-z_4

For the cone: there is probably one vertex that is connected to all other vertices. This vertex is probably easy to find for you. Let's call that p.
Take three vertex other than p. Find the circle passing through those vertices. Call that c. The distance between p and c is the height. The distance between c and any vertex other than p would be the radius. To find the circle passing through three points, you again need to solve a system of equations with three unknowns. As the equation of a circle is (x-a)^2+(y-b)^2=r^2. You need to put the values of your three points in the equation and find a,b, and r. Note that this equation assumes that the circle is in 2D. To use it for 3D, you need to first find the plane passing through these three points. If you do not want to go through all these. you can again average all vertices except p and find the center of the circle. the radius would be the distance between the center and any point. I actually assumed that the circles and spheres in your input are uniformly sampled which is the case for most of the available Obj files for these shapes.